# Is the Minkowski distance actually the $p$-norm function?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

The [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) of order $p$ between two points

$${\displaystyle X=(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}),Y=(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots ,y_{n})\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}}$$

is defined as

$${\displaystyle D\left(X,Y\right)=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}-y_{i}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}}.$$

The [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) of a vector ${\displaystyle \mathbf {x} =(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})}$ is

$$\left\|\mathbf {x} \right\|_{p}:={\bigg (}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|^{p}{\bigg )}^{1/p}.$$

It seems that the Minkowski distance is actually the $p$-norm function, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in the sense that the Minkowski distance is indeed the metric that is induced by the $p$-norm, i.e.
$$D(X,Y)=\|X-Y\|_p \quad \text{for all $X,Y\in\Bbb R^n$}.$$
Note however that, strictly-speaking, the statement "the Minkowski distance **is** the $p$-norm function" does not make sense, as $D$ has the domain $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ (it has two arguments, so to speak), while the $p$-norm is defined for elements in $\Bbb R^n$ (it has only one argument).

PS: You might want to include the dependence on $p$ in your notation for the Minkowski-distance, i.e. write $D_p$ instead of just $D$.