# Is $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ the domain of Minkowski distance $D(X,Y)=\|X-Y\|_p \quad \text{for all } X,Y\in\Bbb R^n.$

Tags: probability

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3311581/678038) says the Minkowski distance,

$D(X,Y)=\|X-Y\|_p \quad \text{for all } X,Y\in\Bbb R^n$

has the domain $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$, since it has two arguments.

I guess the domain may be still $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$D(X,Y)$ takes two argument vectors, $X$ and $Y$, which are both $\mathbb{R}^n$, and this makes the domain $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. If the domain was $\mathbb{R}^n$, it means you need $n$ inputs to execute the function, however $D(X,Y)$ needs $2n$ inputs.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a possible confusion, $D(X,Y)$ requires two inputs, $X,Y$. However, the function $\|.\|_p$ requires only one input, thus has domain $\mathbb{R}^n$